# Decrypting a Base64 ciphertext

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encoding

I am working on a challenge that includes decrypting a piece of ciphertext. The sample decryption provided is as follows:
`KDEwMTAwMDExMTAxMDEwMTAwMTEwMDExMTAxMDAxMDAwMDExMTEwMDAwMTEwMTAwMTAxMTAxMTAwMTAxMDEwMCwxMDAxKQ —> HaCkTrIcK`

My first attempt was to try decoding it as base64 and I could get the following:
`(101000111010101001100111010010000111100001101001011011001010100,1001)`

It seems to be a couple of encrypted binary text along with a key (most probably) but I couldn't find a way to decode it.

So, my question is - is there any way for me to figure out just how the binary data is encoded and how to decode it?

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question that fits here.

Comment: Hint:  Convert the part after the comma (1001) to decimal, and you get 9.  Let's call this K (for key).  Now, take the first 7 bits (1010001), and convert this to decimal, and you get 81.  Now, subtract K, and you get 72.  72 is ascii for H.  Now take the next 7 bits (1101010), convert these to decimal, you get 106.  Again, subtract K, and you get 97.  97 is ascii for a.  See the pattern?

Comment: @mti2935 that's some amazing sleuthing there!

Comment: Thanks @schroeder.  I must have too much time on my hands...